# Test with espresso with "hasTextColor"

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-espresso, textcolor

How can I make a espresso test with the color of the text?
Currently use [hasTextColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#hasTextColor(int)):

```
onView(withId(R.id.editText)).check(matches(hasTextColor(Color.BLACK)));
```

But the error occurs:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff000000
>   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
>
> ...

Details:

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/editText"
 android:textColor="#ff000000"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check against a color defined in the resources like `hasTextColor(R.color.red)`

It's also written in the documentation link you provided:
`colorResId : int`

Comment: Would you know how to get EditText's font size?
I have an open question about this, could you help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398659/check-the-font-size-height-and-width-of-the-edittext-with-espresso